# Azure Update Module - Data factory missing?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-data-factory

https://github.com/microsoft/AzureAutomation-Account-Modules-Update

Trying to update Azure Modules but one of the modules does not get updated. Not sure if this module is part of the script provided by Microsoft

```
AzurmeRm.DataFactoryv2
```

Datafactory  can't start without running the module above.  So you have to upload manually and run the runbook.

Is there a way to incorporate the module above with the automation powershell provided by Microsoft ?

I appreciate any help and tips

Comment: What is the current version of `AzureRM.DataFactoryV2` module you have ?

Comment: I have the latest one. I believe the  Automation Account  update did not include the AzureRM.DataFactoryV2 module inside

Comment: Automation account's update button has not been working for me the last few months.

Comment: Azure changed it - you must import the ps1 provided on  https://github.com/microsoft/AzureAutomation-Account-Modules-Update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its missing, you can import it going here:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.DataFactoryV2/0.5.8

And click on the tab 'Azure Automation', then the blue button 'Deploy to Azure Automation'.

Hope this helped!

Comment: But why is not included in their update ? is there a way to get the module datafactory and import into the powershell

Comment: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.DataFactoryV2/0.5.9/Content/AzureRM.DataFactoryV2.psd1    - get this content and copy inside  of the update power shell